# Java: sorting/arranging arrays based on user input

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How can I sort this array based on user input? While using a constructor, I am returning values to the create the output. What I'd like to do is after receiving how the user would like to arrange his/her inputs, I'd like to perform something like an `Arrays.sort(books[x].getBook());`

But this does not work. Is there a way to arrange the returned values for each input? The following is the error I receive upon using the code below within each `if` statement, although `getBooks()` is very well in existence:

**Error log**

```
LibraryBookSort.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
        Arrays.sort(books[x].getBooks());
                            ^
symbol:   method getBooks()
location: class LibraryBook
1 error
```

**Code**

```
  public class LibraryBookSort {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    LibraryBook[] books = new LibraryBook[5];

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        books[x] = new LibraryBook();
    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {

        // Get title
        System.out.print("Enter the title of a book: ");
        String title = input.nextLine();
        books[x].setBook(title);

        // Get author
        System.out.print("Enter the author of this book: ");
        String author = input.nextLine();
        books[x].setAuthor(title);

        // Get page count
        System.out.print("Enter the number of pages for this book: ");
        int pages = input.nextInt();
        books[x].setPages(pages);

        input.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("How would you like to organize your values?");
    System.out.println("Sort by title > Enter 1: ");
    System.out.println("Sort by author's last name > Enter 2: ");
    System.out.print("Sort by page count > Enter 3: ");

    int sortBy = input.nextInt();

    // Sort by title
    if(sortBy == 1) {
        //????;
    }
    // Sort by author
    else if(sortBy == 2) {
        //????;
    }
    // Sort by page count
    else if(sortBy == 3) {
        //????;
    }

    // Print sorted array >> Use of constructor
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Book ");
        System.out.println("Title: " + books[x].getBook());
        System.out.println("Author: " + books[x].getAuthor());
        System.out.println("Page Count: " + books[x].getPages());            
    }}}
```

The following will arrange my inputs using a comparator. However, the question remains, is there another approach to sorting this data outside of using a comparator?

```
   class TitleComparator implements Comparator {

     public int compare(Object book1, Object book2) {

    String title1 = ((LibraryBook) book1).getBook();
    String title2 = ((LibraryBook) book2).getBook();

    return title1.compareTo(title2);
    }}
```

Comment: Where is `Arrays.sort(books[x].getBooks());` line in your code? Always share the code relevant to exception.

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: Take a look on Comparators and Arrys/Collections class

Comment: I deleted the Arrays.sort()... it doesn't work

Comment: I am familiar with comparators, however my professor will not allow them because we have not covered that material yet. Is there a way around using implement/comparators?

Comment: Your class error doesn't match the class you're showing us.  Further, to the point of `Comparator`:  that'd be the simplest way to do it.  If your professor doesn't allow it, you *really* should talk it over with them.  Also, did you remember to `import java.util.Arrays`?

Comment: yes, I imported java.util.Arrays. Also edited the code to represent the error. This is the error I received based on my initial code. I changed the class in order to not have my name displayed.

Comment: Any chance you've been covering sorting algorithms?  I suspect the professor is wanting you to use one of the algorithms he's covered here.  CS101 is bubble sort, since it's simple and you're not on the hook for performance at scale.

Comment: see to sort any custom object in java, comparator is mandatory for direct sort or else we have to write our own code replacing comparator which involves sorting logic. so go through some of the sorting logic and use it. but before that check with your professor about comparator..then proceed

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add like this and it is working. Store the books inside the collection. So that you can make use of Collections.sort function and Comparator.

LibraryBookSort.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LibraryBookSort {

private static ArrayList<LibraryBook> list;

public static void main(String[] args) {

LibraryBook[] books = new LibraryBook[5];

for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    books[x] = new LibraryBook();
}

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

list = new ArrayList<LibraryBook>();
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {

    // Get title
    System.out.print("Enter the title of a book: ");
    String title = input.nextLine();
    books[x].setBook(title);

    // Get author
    System.out.print("Enter the author of this book: ");
    String author = input.nextLine();
    books[x].setAuthor(title);

    // Get page count
    System.out.print("Enter the number of pages for this book: ");
    int pages = input.nextInt();
    books[x].setPages(pages);
    list.add(books[x]);
    input.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("How would you like to organize your values?");
System.out.println("Sort by title > Enter 1: ");
System.out.println("Sort by author's last name > Enter 2: ");
System.out.print("Sort by page count > Enter 3: ");

int sortBy = input.nextInt();

// Sort by title
if(sortBy == 1) {
    Collections.sort(list,new TitleComparator());
}
// Sort by author
else if(sortBy == 2) {
    //????;
}
// Sort by page count
else if(sortBy == 3) {
    //????;
}

 for(LibraryBook st: list){  
    System.out.println(st.title+" "+st.author+" "+st.pages);  
}  
}}
```

Also added another class TitleComparator.java.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class TitleComparator implements Comparator <LibraryBook>{

@Override
public int compare(LibraryBook arg0, LibraryBook arg1) {
        
    return arg0.title.compareTo(arg1.title);
}
}
```

This is for sort books based on the title. You can also add PageComparator and AuthorComparator for the other two options.