# Java: Sorting user-input array upon return

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How can I sort the following?

```
System.out.println("Title: " + titleArray[x].getBook());
```

This line gets its data from a user-inputted Title. If I try

```
System.out.println("Title: " + Arrays.sort(titleArray[x].getBook()));
```

I receive the following error:

```
  LibraryBookSort.java:66: error: no suitable method found for sort(String)
          System.out.println("Title: " + Arrays.sort(titleArray[x].getBook()));
                                             ^
  method Arrays.<T#1>sort(T#1[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
  (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  method Arrays.<T#2>sort(T#2[],Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
  (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  method Arrays.sort(Object[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  method Arrays.sort(Object[]) is not applicable
  (actual argument String cannot be converted to Object[] by method invocation conversion)
  method Arrays.sort(double[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  method Arrays.sort(double[]) is not applicable
  (actual argument String cannot be converted to double[] by method invocation conversion)
  method Arrays.sort(float[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  method Arrays.sort(float[]) is not applicable
  (actual argument String cannot be converted to float[] by method invocation conversion)
  method Arrays.sort(byte[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  method Arrays.sort(byte[]) is not applicable
  (actual argument String cannot be converted to byte[] by method invocation conversion)
  method Arrays.sort(char[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  method Arrays.sort(char[]) is not applicable
  (actual argument String cannot be converted to char[] by method invocation conversion)
  method Arrays.sort(short[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  method Arrays.sort(short[]) is not applicable
  (actual argument String cannot be converted to short[] by method invocation conversion)
  method Arrays.sort(long[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  method Arrays.sort(long[]) is not applicable
  (actual argument String cannot be converted to long[] by method invocation conversion)
  method Arrays.sort(int[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  method Arrays.sort(int[]) is not applicable
  (actual argument String cannot be converted to int[] by method invocation conversion)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
  T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(T#1[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#1>)
  T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(T#2[],Comparator<? super T#2>)
  1 error
```

I'm assuming this is due to the constructor not allowing sort upon return? 
Java.util.Arrays; is imported as well.

EDIT: After trying String sortedTitles[] = titleArray[x].getBook(); outside of the Sysout in order to establish a new string[], received the following error...

```
  LibraryBookSort.java:63: error: incompatible types
        String sortedTitles[] = titleArray[x].getBook();
                                                     ^
  required: String[]
  found:    String
  1 error
```

How can I sort the returned Array?

Comment: `Arrays.sort` is a void method, also there is no sort method that takes a String as parameter.

Comment: I doubt `titleArray[x].getBook()` returns an array. *no suitable method found for `sort(String)`*

Comment: In fact it does return an array, however not sorted

Comment: Are you claiming that Array.sort only returns sorting for ints/bytes?

Comment: @ewbrowning No, where did you read that? `Arrays.sort` returns nothing. It just sorts the array you pass as parameter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986386/sorting-an-array-of-strings-with-java

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't ***return*** the array. The signature of `Arrays.sort` is `public static void sort()`.

Comment: Understood, so how can I sort my array that has been returned already?

Comment: @ewbrowning Call `Arrays.sort`?

Comment: Sort it outside of your `sysout` call. And don't try to call `Arrays.sort` on a single `String`

Comment: this still isn't working. I will edit this question with a more updates...

Comment: titleArray[x] is not the array.  It is element x of the array

Comment: titleArray[x].getBook() is not an array of Strings. It's a String. That's what the error message is telling you. Sorting a string doesn't mean anything. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is my code... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434076/java-sorting-arranging-arrays-based-on-user-input

Comment: @ewbrowning That error means that you're trying to use a method that doesn't exist. one `s` too much in books?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It does exist, I just can't sort because the method I'm trying to sort is null? Apparently? That's what I've been told.

Comment: You have to sort it and then use the original.  You don't get a brand new array when you call `Arrays.sort()`.  That's the whole point of it being `void` - it doesn't return something new; it just manipulates the original.